# Swift: Coding rule of optional. Which is swift's style returning nil or []

Tags: ios, swift, coding-style

I have some find methods in model classes. Which is better between returning nil or [](empty array) when data is empty. Please take a look below. I think (2) is better because I do not need nil check.

```
(1) nil

func findAll() -> [Sample]? {
    return nil
}

if let results = DataManager().findAll() {
    self.results = results
}

(2) empty arrray

func findAll() -> [Sample] {
    if results.count > 0 {
      return results
    }
    return []
}

self.results    = DataManager().findAll()
```

---

Update

I changed model class's method.

```
(1) nil

func findAll() -> [Sample]? {
    var results = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error) as [Sample]
    if results.count > 0 {
      return results
    }
    return nil
}

if let results = DataManager().findAll() {
    self.results = results
}

(2) empty arrray

func findAll() -> [Sample] {
    var results = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error) as [Sample]
    if results.count > 0 {
      return results
    }
    return []
}

self.results    = DataManager().findAll()
```

Comment: This is not an opinion based question.  It's about types, and the OP is right to have the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Optional` is a great way to enhance an existing type to express the idea that "there isn't one".

Collections such as sets, arrays and trees *already* have that capability - the empty collection.

It's totally legitimate to return `[]` from a function which returns a collection type.  Especially in the case you give above, since if the question is really 'how many are there', then `[].count` equals `0`, which is correct, but `Optional.None<Thing>?.count` would return `Optional<Int>.None`; which doesn't accurately represent the number of members.

`Optional.None` is equivalent to Objective-c's `nil` but with type checking.

---

You can (and should) also view `Optional` as a special case of a collection!  It's a collection which can either hold zero (`None`) or (`Some` or just) one of the thing in question - and no more.

So for the analogous method `find` which returns the first matching element, or none, Optionals are appropriate, since `find` only needs to return one thing and no more, or nothing.

Comment: Thank you so much. I found that I need to understand optional and nil. And 'find' method you mentioned is what I wanted to ask.